# _.concat lodash vs Array.prototype.concat()

Tags: javascript, lodash

what is the difference between `_.concat` lodash and `Array.prototype.concat()` ?.

Comment: One uses the Lodash library for the operation, the other the native implementation.

Comment: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.15/lodash.js#L6911

Comment: The source code for `lodash`'s `concat` function is freely available. You can check it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

welcome to Stackoverflow!

The functions work the same way, but the syntax is different:

_.concat ->

```
let array1 = [1, 2, 3];
let array2 = [4, 5, 6],
let array3 = [7, 8, 9];
let allArrays = _.concat(array1 , array2 , array3);
console.log(allArrays ); // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

array.concat ->

```
let array1 = [1, 2, 3];
let array2 = [4, 5, 6],
let array3 = [7, 8, 9];
let allArrays = [].concat(array1 , array2 , array3);
console.log(allArrays ); // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

or array.concat ->

```
let array1 = [1, 2, 3];
let array2 = [4, 5, 6],
let array3 = [7, 8, 9];
let allArrays = [];
allArrays.concat(array1 , array2 , array3);
console.log(allArrays ); // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

basically the array.concat is called from ARRAYs and _.concat doesn't need an array to be called